# EF: IQueryable not loading children

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a parent model with different child models through foreign key relationship (lazy loading -> `virtual` is on).

It seems that using query like

```
Parent.Where(x=> x.something == true).AsQueryable()
```

is not predictable. That is, sometimes the children are loaded while sometimes they are not (**NOTE**: This has started happening with EF 6.1.3).

I wonder if there is a guaranteed way to lazy load children on demand without using `include`.

TO BE EXACT:

```
var list = Parent.Where(x=> ...).Take(1);
foreach(var parent in list){
   var childName = parent.Child.Name; //NOTE: Parent and Child are related by foreign key (some Id)
}
```

Problem is Child is found to be null even though the record in database exists.

Do note, `Include` works fine at the same time `Take(50) instead of Take(1)` too works fine.

Comment: Read about [loading related entities](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/entity-framework/4678/loading-related-entities#t=201608161252580934366)

Comment: @AdilMammadov Went through the link, I can verify that I have lazyloading enable, however, it doesn't seem to work as the child is null.

Comment: İf it works sometimes, does not work other times, then I think, it is because  of data in your database. please veiry that data exists in database. Or alternatively you can use *EagerLaoding*

Comment: Indeed. It sounds like you need more of _eager_ loading rather than _lazy_

Comment: @uteist Why wouldn't lazy loading work? The Data record is there in the database to lazy load?

Comment: Not saying it _won't_ work but with lazy load, you usually have multiple sql queries running against your db which might be why you hit some parts being null. With eager loading, you also load related entities with single, a more "heavier" query. You can also check this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Quite strange... I use 6.1.3 and I use lazy load very very often (for the reason you wrote below). What do you do with the IQueryable after the statement you show? I think the problem is from `Parent.Where(x=> x.something == true).AsQueryable()` to the materialization (`ToList()`)

Comment: @bubi After `Parent.Where().AsQueryable()` -> `Parent.Child.Name` I try extracting name but `Child is null`. Even though Parent and Child are related with a foreign key which is `PRESENT`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use Inculde method, like this:

Parent.Include("Child").Where(x=> x.something == true);

and you don't need to call the AsQueryable() as the  line above return AsQueryable

Comment: I did note in the question, that I don't want to use `include` as that would mean extra code and someone in future adds a new table and forgets to use `include`. Would appreciate a similar way to lazy load all children.

Answer (score 0):

I've also noticed this behaviour. I've always just used include but if you don't want to, you could do something like:

```
var list = Parent.Where(p => p.Something == true).Select(p => p.Child.Parent)
```

I don't really like it but it forces the child to load, then returns the parents.

To ensure lazy loading will work, make sure you have `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` in your connection string as it won't always work without it (it might work but not always)

Note: It's worth noting I've experienced this issue when the database is under heavy load. Trying it again a second time works fine but sometimes, the initial query doesn't lazy load the elements properly.